# Virutalbox USB Linux Host Windows 10 Guest

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

For the life of me I can't access USB from a Windows 10 guest, hosted on Pop OS 22.04.

- Virtual Box 6.1.36_Ubuntu r152435
- Host Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
- Guest Windows 10 21H1

I am in vboxusers group:

```
$ groups $USER
myname : myname adm sudo lpadmin vboxusers
```

I have installed guest additions to Windows 10:
[image]

I have installed the virtual box extension pack:
[image]

I can't see any USB devices to add in settings:

When I try to add USB devices,

[image]

If I try to add a new filter,

> <no devices available>

I add the empty string filter, and still can't see anything.
I've tried USB 1.0, 2.0, and 3.0.

How do I access my USB ports?

Comment: Did you add the VBOX Guest Extensions to the Windows Guest?  You need to do that

Comment: @John yes I do mention that but I'll try to make it more clear

Comment: Try to have the VM Powered Off, rather than Saved. Once that is done the USB options should be accessible.  The VirtualBox Extension Pack should also be installed on the host.

Comment: I honestly think I just needed to reboot my host OS. whenever docs state to log off/on I always seem to  need to reboot

Comment: So what's the current situation?

Comment: @harrymc I'm good to go, going to delete question

Comment: Whatever the solution, you should either put up an answer of your own, or award the bounty to the advice that helped. That will help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got most of the bases covered, however VirtualBox in your post is v6.36.x, whereas Guest Additions is v6.32.x.

Reinstall Guest Additions using the same version as your VirtualBox installation.

You also need to restart (maybe only log in/out) after adding yourself to group vboxusers (though you've probably done this already).

Comment: Thanks, followed your instructions and no change. Still cannot see USB